# Can Not Disable UFW In Rescue System Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux-networking, ufw, ubuntu-18.04

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, i enabled UFW on my system without thinking about adding the rules, i was tensed about a maleware that i had to remove. And then after enabling UFW i forgot to add the rules, i restarted my dedicated server and as expected the server isnt responding to SSH at all due to no rules.

I rebooted into rescue mode, **fdisk -l** gives me these results

> Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
>   of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop0: 3 GiB, 3221225472 bytes, 6291456 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
>   512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
>   bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
>   C40B2105-ECCE-433A-99D2-FA67E05FA99F
>
> Device        Start         End     Sectors  Size Type /dev/sda1
>   4096    33558527    33554432   16G Linux RAID /dev/sda2  33558528
>   34607103     1048576  512M Linux RAID /dev/sda3  34607104 11721045134
>   11686438031  5.5T Linux RAID /dev/sda4      2048        4095
>   2048    1M BIOS boot
>
> Partition table entries are not in disk order.
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
>   512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
>   bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
>   06EA9ED3-1841-479B-BB28-A7C56A0878FD
>
> Device        Start         End     Sectors  Size Type /dev/sdb1
>   4096    33558527    33554432   16G Linux RAID /dev/sdb2  33558528
>   34607103     1048576  512M Linux RAID /dev/sdb3  34607104 11721045134
>   11686438031  5.5T Linux RAID /dev/sdb4      2048        4095
>   2048    1M BIOS boot
>
> Partition table entries are not in disk order.
>
> Disk /dev/md0: 32 GiB, 34326183936 bytes, 67043328 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576
>   bytes
>
> Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/md2: 10.9 TiB, 11966643961856 bytes, 23372351488 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
>   512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes /
>   1048576 bytes

So i mount mount **/dev/md2 /mnt** because thats where i think the ufw.conf file is

After mounting i cd to /etc/ufw but the problem is there is now ufw.conf file in this folder so that i can disable it, i tried making a new file and putting enabled=no but that dosent help, can someone please help me out?

Comment: Problem solved by

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf

sudo chroot /mnt

apt-get purge ufw

exit

sudo umount /mnt/sys

sudo umount /mnt/proc

sudo umount /mnt/dev

sudo umount /mnt

reboot

and now server is accepting SSH connections..`

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so the question doesn't pop up again and again in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fixed the issue

```
sudo mount /dev/md2 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf

sudo chroot /mnt

apt-get purge ufw

exit

sudo umount /mnt/sys

sudo umount /mnt/proc

sudo umount /mnt/dev

sudo umount /mnt

reboot

and now server is accepting SSH connections..
```

Comment: Please, consider marking Bond's answer as a solution. Yours is an answer for sure, but that one is much easier. Your solution needs clarification, additional commands involved here can lead to worse situation.

Answer (score 11):

the easiest way is probably to mount the partition and then change the ufw.conf file to not autostart

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=no
```