# Putty connection time out after enabling firewall

Tags: ufw, putty

I have a problem after enabling ufw firewall. Everything was working well for the last few months but I wanted to add SSL and redirect traffic http->https so I wanted to open port 443. What I did - `$ sudo ufw enable` . I got info that firewall is enabled. After that putty disconnected and now when I want to connect I'm getting connection time out. of course - I cannot login to disable firewall again so what can I do ? How can I fix that ? Any ideas please ? I'm more programmer than devops so sorry for basic question but I;m going crazy here :)

Comment: Log in through a local console or a rescue environment and disable it.

Comment: `Any ideas?` For future reference, if you go sans host firewall, you cannot turn it on and expect no impact.

Comment: Sure , I know. I Just didn't expect I won't be able to even login to server. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Not Disable UFW In Rescue System Ubuntu 18](https://serverfault.com/questions/957740/can-not-disable-ufw-in-rescue-system-ubuntu-18) -- have a look at TBOND's answer.

Comment: I'm confused. How does enabling `ufw` help in redirecting http to https?

Comment: I wanted to open and check port 443